# Calling methods from other classes in FXML controller

Tags: java, controller, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm currently doing a homework assignment, creating a web browser with multiple tabs in javaFX using the scene builder and coding in the FXML controller. I'm fairly new, but I can't seem to figure out how to access other methods from other classes within the controller class.

I have one file name FXMLDocumentController.java where all my coding is in, and another file just called Name.java which just loads the .fxml document that was created by the scene builder.

```
package name;



public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Tab TabPanel1;

@FXML
private Button backButton;

@FXML
private Button forwardButton;

@FXML
private Button goButton;

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private MenuBar menubar1;

@FXML
private Button stopButton;

@FXML
private AnchorPane textArea1;

@FXML
private ComboBox urlAddress;

@FXML
private WebView webview1;
private WebEngine webEngine;

@FXML
void backButtonClickAction(ActionEvent event) {
    WebHistory history = webEngine.getHistory();
    int back = history.getCurrentIndex();
    if (back <= 0) {
    } else {
        history.go(-1);
    }

}

@FXML
void forwardButtonClickAction(ActionEvent event) {
    WebHistory history = webEngine.getHistory();
    int fwd = history.getCurrentIndex();
    fwd++;
    ObservableList<WebHistory.Entry> entryList = history.getEntries();
    int stop = entryList.size();
    if (fwd == stop) {
    } else {
        history.go(1);
    }
}

@FXML
void stopButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().cancel();
}

@FXML
void goButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String url = urlAddress.getValue().toString();
    if (url.startsWith("http://www.")) {
        webEngine.load(url);
    } else if (url.startsWith("www.")) {
        webEngine.load("http://" + url);
    } else {
        webEngine.load("http://www." + url);
    }

    //TabPanel1.setText(webEngine.getLocation());
    //System.out.println(webEngine.getTitle());
}

@FXML
void urlAddressEnter(ActionEvent event) {
    String url = urlAddress.getValue().toString();
    if (url.startsWith("http://www.")) {
        webEngine.load(url);
    } else if (url.startsWith("www.")) {
        webEngine.load("http://" + url);
    } else {
        webEngine.load("http://www." + url);
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rs) {
    assert TabPanel1 != null : "fx:id=\"TabPanel1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    assert backButton != null : "fx:id=\"backButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    assert forwardButton != null : "fx:id=\"forwardButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    assert goButton != null : "fx:id=\"goButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    assert label != null : "fx:id=\"label\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    assert menubar1 != null : "fx:id=\"menubar1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    assert stopButton != null : "fx:id=\"stopButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    assert textArea1 != null : "fx:id=\"textArea1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    assert urlAddress != null : "fx:id=\"urlAddress\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    assert webview1 != null : "fx:id=\"webview1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    webEngine = webview1.getEngine();
    getHistory();

}

private void getHistory() {
    final WebHistory history = webEngine.getHistory();
    history.getEntries().addListener(new ListChangeListener<WebHistory.Entry>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends WebHistory.Entry> c) {
            c.next();
            for (WebHistory.Entry e : c.getRemoved()) {
                urlAddress.getItems().remove(e.getUrl());
            }
            for (WebHistory.Entry e : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                urlAddress.getItems().add(e.getUrl());
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

This creates a browser with back, forward, stop and a history drop down list. I now need to create multiple tabs so I need to create a new .java file that will create new tabs and have a method to return the current webengine, so I can implement all of these features.

The problem is, when I create a new class I can't access it from the controller, I keep getting errors. For instance, if I had a new file named BrowserTab with a method called newBrowserTab, how could I call on that method from the controller file with all my other code. I figured it would be something like this:

```
BrowserTab.newBrowserTab(tabPane, "New Tab")
```

Answer (score 0):

See [static methods](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function/) for a quick solution.

Static methods are the most straight-forward, but are not very object-oriented.  There are other methods of [passing object instances around to FXML controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml) which don't involve static methods and provide greater encapsulation, instancing, polymorphism support, etc. with less global state.